# TFS 2015 Build Automation: Get Sources Always runs before the first task

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfs, continuous-integration

I am using a TFS 2015 Release manager for continuous integration to our project. In the build definition,  I have put a Powershell task to update the project assemblies to new build version before I actually build the project using Visual Studio Build task.

[image]

The problem starts when I try to run the build , There is always a Hidden "Get Sources" task running before it starts the first task which is powershell to update the assemblies of the project. So even though I am updating the project assemblies the change is not reflecting in the artifact staging directory after the build is complete.

**My question**: How to prevent this Hidden **Get Sources task** being called by default before the Powershell task?

Comment: "update the assemblies of the project". without "Get Sources", there may not be a project / source code (git clone) to work with, is that what your powershell taks expects?

Comment: @MartinUllrich The powershell is working as expected to update the build version of the project but the updated build version is not reflected in the final build. This is because the TFS 2015 release manager's build definition downloads the entire project first and works on the tasks we have defined. I want to stop this default behavior of downloading the project first and I want to update the build version from powershell task and then force the TFS RM to download the project.

Comment: Is this using the ""new"" build&release system or the classic release management?
I don't get how the build number would affect the source being downloaded.. the build job that vsts-agent receives is basically "build this source using this definition"

Comment: @MartinUllrich looks like my issue is similer to the one mentioned in [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1015) but the solution provided there wouldn't work.

Comment: Where is the file your powershell script update? In the TFS version control or in the build agent?

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t the way to prevent Get Sources task being called before another task.

The workaround is that, you can create another build definition for CI build (Triggers > Check Continuous integration), after that this build will be triggered after the first build update project assemblies and check in to the source control.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you also want to **really get latest** at the point in time when the build runs (not when it was queued) just like  [Hidden "Getting source"-task runs too soon.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1015)

*ericsciple's* solution works well, you could run a batch script as the first step of your build.

```
CD /d "%Build_SourcesDirectory%"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" get * /r
```

This batch is using a `tf.exe` command, which need VS installed in your build agent machine.    And the command should be located at the corresponding path on your build agent.  `Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0` which stands for VS2015.